# Android Studio This version is deprecated. Details: For more information, refer to documentation for specific features ERROR

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-mlkit

I'm currently making a simple Google Lens application through firebase and I have this issue. I searched it on Google and it says that this version has a bug and when I try to convert the deprecated code, my MainActivity.java begins to get tons of errors. Is there anything i can do?

Error quote:

> This version is deprecated. Details: For more information, refer to documentation for specific features

My Dependencies: (i specified the error code)

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.3' (ERROR CODE)
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-image-label-model:20.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the list of available repositories for [`firebase-ml-vision`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-ml-vision).

Replace the latest version with your version, which right now the latest version is : `24.1.0`

So you can change version like below: ([source](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-ml-vision/24.1.0))

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.1.0'
```

If your problem didn't fixed, make sure to check the requirements for this or relative dependencies, in other-hand if upgrading didn't worked, make sure to provide more details related to activity.

Comment: Hey there, first of all thank you for the answer. As you said, I tried to change the error implementation with the new one and I still have the same error. If you want anything from my codes I can gladly send it. I'm waiting for your answer.

Comment: Not working. It's still saying that "This library has been depreciated"

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying firebase on-device APIs, they should be deprecated and please migrate to use our new ML Kit APIs.

https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration/android

Comment: Hey, thank you for the posting new version site. I can see the difference between the old one and new one but I can't figure how to update old codings. Can I have some help please?

Comment: Error in dependencies have changed but I got 12 error codes in MainActivity.java. Here's the image link: https://imgur.com/a/xpvWoEt

Comment: Besides the dependencies, you need to also update the code.

Comment: Please follow https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration/android thoroughly. It also has old and new code examples below that you check for reference: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration/android#update_method_names

Comment: I reviewed ml-kit site, and saw the old-new versions of the mlkit. But I'm new at Android Studio, so I didn't know how to organize new codes. I can't open the screenshot links, site wants me to sign in. Can you try to upload png's on a new site? Imgur would be awesome. By the way, I'm truly appreciated for your help, thank you so much.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/fvCQJhf

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/rQtsqjm

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice the screenshots don't work for you, added the new links.

Comment: For imgur.com/a/xpvWoEt, you need to change the code something like:

InputImage image = InputImage.fromBitmap(imageBitmap, rotationDegree);
ImageLabeler labeler = ImageLabeling.getClient(ImageLabelerOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

Comment: ```
labeler.process(image).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<ImageLabel>>() {
 @Override
     public void onSuccess(List<ImageLabel> labels) {
         String searchQuery = labels.get(0).getText();
         getSearchResults(searchQuery);
     }
 }
 .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(...);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can refer https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/image-labeling/android#java for how to use the ML Kit image labeling APIs

Comment: https://justpaste.it/53uz2 for code change example for imgur.com/a/xpvWoEt